# Hyperledger composer test code

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I was following the instructions on IBM hyperledger composer **developer guide**, but when I did compiling, it failed and appeared this error.

```html
> mocha -t 0 --recursive && cucumber-js

  Sample
    1) "before each" hook for "Alice can read all of the assets"


  0 passing (912ms)
  1 failing

  1) Sample "before each" hook for "Alice can read all of the assets":
     SyntaxError: Failed to parse /Users/calvinlin007/Documents/hyperledger-composer/my-network/lib/sample.js: The keyword 'const' is reserved (17:0)
      at new Script (node_modules/composer-common/lib/introspect/script.js:55:27)
      at ScriptManager.createScript (node_modules/composer-common/lib/scriptmanager.js:61:16)
      at Object.process (node_modules/composer-common/lib/businessnetworkdefinition.js:507:69)
      at Function.processFile (node_modules/composer-common/lib/businessnetworkdefinition.js:578:27)
      at items.forEach (node_modules/composer-common/lib/businessnetworkdefinition.js:563:39)
      at Array.forEach (native)
      at Function.processDirectory (node_modules/composer-common/lib/businessnetworkdefinition.js:562:15)
      at Function.fromDirectory (node_modules/composer-common/lib/businessnetworkdefinition.js:498:35)
      at adminConnection.createProfile.then.then (test/sample.js:66:50)

npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test-inner"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-network@0.1.6 test-inner: `mocha -t 0 --recursive && cucumber-js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-network@0.1.6 test-inner script 'mocha -t 0 --recursive && cucumber-js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-network package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     mocha -t 0 --recursive && cucumber-js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-network
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-network
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/calvinlin007/Documents/hyperledger-composer/my-network/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

This is my **.eslintrc.yml** configuration

```html
env:
    es6: true
    node: true
    mocha: true
extends: 'eslint:recommended'
parserOptions:
    ecmaVersion: 2015
    sourceType:
        - script
```

Cuz I have searched the problem and it should be EMCAScript version,
but I tried changing it and it didn't work.

I've checked my macOS is 10.12. and here's my package.json

```html
{
  "engines": {
    "composer": "^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0"
  },
  "name": "my-network",
  "version": "0.1.6",
  "description": "My Commodity Trading network",
  "networkImage": "https://hyperledger.github.io/composer-sample-networks/packages/basic-sample-network/networkimage.svg",
  "networkImageanimated": "https://hyperledger.github.io/composer-sample-networks/packages/basic-sample-network/networkimageanimated.svg",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "mkdirp ./dist ; composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/my-network.bna",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "postlint": "npm run licchk",
    "licchk": "license-check",
    "postlicchk": "npm run doc",
    "doc": "jsdoc --pedantic --recurse -c jsdoc.json",
    "test-inner": "mocha -t 0 --recursive && cucumber-js",
    "test-cover": "nyc npm run test-inner",
    "test": "npm run test-inner"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "sample",
    "composer",
    "composer-network"
  ],
  "author": "Hyperledger Composer",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserfs": "^1.2.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^6.0.0",
    "composer-admin": "^0.11.0",
    "composer-cli": "^0.11.0",
    "composer-client": "^0.11.0",
    "composer-connector-embedded": "^0.11.0",
    "composer-cucumber-steps": "^0.11.0",
    "cucumber": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint": "^3.6.1",
    "istanbul": "^0.4.5",
    "jsdoc": "^3.4.1",
    "license-check": "^1.1.5",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "nyc": "^11.0.2"
  },
  "license-check-config": {
    "src": [
      "**/*.js",
      "!./coverage/**/*",
      "!./node_modules/**/*",
      "!./out/**/*",
      "!./scripts/**/*"
    ],
    "path": "header.txt",
    "blocking": true,
    "logInfo": false,
    "logError": true
  },
  "nyc": {
    "exclude": [
      "coverage/**",
      "features/**",
      "out/**",
      "test/**"
    ],
    "reporter": [
      "text-summary",
      "html"
    ],
    "all": true,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "statements": 100,
    "branches": 100,
    "functions": 100,
    "lines": 100
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem @@ ?

Comment: hi there
1. Have you got a supported platform? Currently thats - Mac OS 10.12 - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/installing/development-tools.html for supported environments firstly.
2. can we see your package.json file please? 
3. can you return the output of `npm list -g --depth=0` thanks

The Developer Guide you refer to is https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html and should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your first problem - the sample.js test script - you have copied the *Unit Test* script contents  into `lib/sample.js` and that is why you have your problems - ie 'const' error - that file is the Transaction Processor functions script. You should (as per the Developer Tutorial) paste the Unit test script into the file located at `test/sample.js`.  I think perhaps the fact that the filenames (in both 'lib' and 'test' subdirectories) are the same, has caused some confusion - think I will get that changed to improve user experience.  The other Angular error (mentioned earlier) still stands.

On your second posting (Angular module errors). A local Composer playground install has dependencies on Angular (note the Developer guide uses the online playground). Check out package.json for that list of angular dependencies. Doesn't look like your playground installed correctly, if its showing missing dependencies (@angular/core etc) Suggest to clear down `docker ps -aq | xargs docker rm -f` and `docker images -aq | xargs docker rmi -f` (warning: clears down all docker containers in your dev environment) then install it (as a non-privileged user) using the one-liner - ie `npm uninstall -g composer-playground` - installs playground in a docker container using the command  `curl -sSL https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/install-hlfv1.sh | bash` .

Comment: thank you so much, problems solved. Much appreciated.

Comment: don't forget to upvote the response if it helps (it helps others too!)

Answer (score 0):

This is what npm list command returns

```html
Calvinde-MacBook-Air:my-network calvinlin007$ npm list -g --depth=0
/usr/local/lib
├── composer-cli@0.12.2
├── composer-playground@0.12.2
├── composer-rest-server@0.12.2
├── generator-hyperledger-composer@0.12.2
├── npm@3.10.10
└── yo@2.0.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^4.0.3, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@>=4.0.0, required by ngx-clipboard@8.0.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^4.0.3, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@>=4.0.0, required by ngx-clipboard@8.0.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^4.0.3, required by @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser@>=4.0.0, required by ngx-clipboard@8.0.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: core-js@>=2.4.1, required by ngx-clipboard@8.0.4
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@>=2.4.1, required by ngx-window-token@0.0.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@>=2.4.1, required by ngx-window-token@0.0.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser@>=2.4.1, required by ngx-window-token@0.0.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: core-js@>=2.4.1, required by ngx-window-token@0.0.2
```

Comment: Am I missing something @@?